# Cannot access windows share on AWS from home IP

Tags: windows, networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I created a share on my windows instance on AWS.
I have elastic IP.
I opened my home ip address (which is static) for 'all traffic'
However I am unable to access the share, or even see the list of shares.

I can access the share from the other AWS instances I have.

I turned off the windows firewall on the server.

I can access shares through my home router to other places (just testing to make sure my isp doesn't block these connections).

Any ideas how to make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: What about the security group of your AWS instance? Can it accept inbound traffic from your home IP?

Comment: Yes, as I wrote above, I opened my IP for 'all traffic'

Answer (score 1):

Start by checking basic connectivity. You need to check that you can connect to port 445 on the remote IP. Easiest way to do this is with telnet:

```
telnet <elastic IP> 445
```

If you get a "connection refused" (most likely) then you need to start checking what is blocking you. Check for a client side firewall, a router firewall, etc.
Also try connecting to the public IP of the instance, not the elastic IP.